# How prevent word breaking in small mobile views

Tags: css

The H1 title on the below URL :
https://www.purelocal.com.au/celebrity-ink-tattoo-studio-highpoint

In mobile , because of the font size , the words are often cutoff halfway and forced to a new line.
Is the only way to prevent this to use a small font for mobile ?

Answer (score 1):

you could use the css `word-break: break-word;` to break the words on the spaces of words, not on the words itself.

other options for the `word-break` would be `break-all`, `keep-all`, or `normal` (the default value)

[Here is a sample link for the four values of the `word-break` property](https://codepen.io/monkeybanana550/pen/wvgdeXN)

Answer (score 1):

Another way: you can and likely should use a 'css breakpoints' like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px){
 
...
 
}
```

to fine-tune a two or more layouts on your page (e.g. mobile & desktop). This can also include word-break attribute inside.